# Background Image not covering full page height

Tags: html, css

I have set a background-image to my  tag and for some reason the image is not filling out to correspond with the content on the page. The bottom part of my page is just white space with no background image.

I tried to change the height and the width of the image thinking it was a problem with the height. It still didn't work. I then tried to use background-size:cover; and it still left the white space at the bottom. Please help!

This is the link to my work space: https://replit.com/@SRJCEthanWilde/CS50A-Module13-52-JosohamyMendez#find.html

and the link directly to my page is:
https://cs50a-module13-52-josohamymendez.srjcethanwilde.repl.co/find.html

Comment: Please add meaningful code here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using fixed values (such as `px` or `rem`) for the `gap`?

For example:

```css
.grid {
    gap: 2rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .grid {
        gap: 1rem;

    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 425px) {
    .grid {
        gap: 1rem;
    }
```